# how to animate diff images in xna game?

Tags: xna

i am having  19 images , which are animation frames of my player

in below i have created array of texture as frog which is my player.and there are 19 images.how to animate them.

public class Texture
    {
        public static Texture2D mBackground;
        public static Texture2D mBackgroundOne;
        public static Texture2D mBackgroundTwo;
        public static Texture2D grassUp;
        public static Texture2D grassDown;
        public static Texture2D[] frog = new Texture2D[19];
        public static Texture2D[] frogdie = new Texture2D[4];

```
    public static Vector2 position;

    public static void Load()
    {
        mBackground = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("layer_11");
        mBackgroundOne = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("layer_11");
        mBackgroundTwo = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("layer_11");
        grassUp = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("layer_11");
        grassDown = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("layer_11");


        frog[0] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal1");
        frog[1] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal2");
        frog[2] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal3");
        frog[3] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal4");
        frog[4] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal5");
        frog[5] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal6");
        frog[6] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal7");
        frog[7] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal8");
        frog[8] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal9");
        frog[9] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal10");
        frog[10] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal11");
        frog[11] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal12");
        frog[12] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal13");
        frog[13] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal14");
        frog[14] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal15");
        frog[15] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal16");
        frog[16] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal17");
        frog[17] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal18");
        frog[18] = GamePage.contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("player/maindak_normal19");

    }

    public  static void draw(SpriteBatch sprite)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 18; i++)
        {
            sprite.Draw(frog[i],position= new Vector2(100, 100), Color.White);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping with your current structure, you could animate your textures in the following manner:

```cs
//timer
private const float TIME_BETWEEN_FRAME = 0.1f;
private float timer = TIME_BETWEEN_FRAME;

//frame sequence
private int currentFrame = 0;

public void Update(GameTime gametime)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    timer -= elapsed;       //subtract elapsed time from timer
    if (timer <= 0)         //if our timer is elapsed
    {
        currentFrame++;     //next frame
        if (currentFrame >= frog.Count)
            currentFrame = 0;           //If we reach last frame, reset to loop
        timer = TIME_BETWEEN_FRAME;     //reset timer
    }
}

public  void draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(frog[currentFrame], position, Color.White);
}
```

This will work, however, if you want to take it a step further into the right direction, you should look into [SpriteSheets](http://www.berecursive.com/2008/c/sprite-sheets-in-xna-the-basics), which will provide you with a much easier way to manage all of your animations.

Comment: thnxxx its working but whenever i decrease the TIME_BET_FRM it blinks....not a clear animation....any suggestion??

Comment: @user2211593 if it is blinking, most likely one or more of your frames is blank

Comment: @Jon  no i dnt have any frame blank

Comment: @Jon  now when i wanted to jump my player on touch event it displays frames very quickly,,,,,how to slo it down